# HTML table not displaying on button click using display block

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two table which both hide on page load but based on condition display one table and hide other table vise versa. Problem is table not displaying on action.

I tried to hide table using jquery but user can see table 1 or 2 sec.when load page. So thats reason to do hide using css display none.

Question 1: How to make work table on action ? Question 2: How to display table on same position when display table and hide another ?

Here is my code:

```js
document.getElementById("test1").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("test2").style.display="none";
```

```css
#test1,#test2{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<table id="test1" class="display" width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><b>Name :</b> <label for="nme" style="vertical-align: middle"></label></td>
    <td><b>Expanded Name :</b> <label for="frml_nme" style="vertical-align: middle"></label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="test2" class="display" width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><b>Feed Name :</b> <label for="feed_id" style="vertical-align: middle"></label></td>
    <td><b>Source :</b> <label for="source" style="vertical-align: middle"></label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What does **make work table on action** mean?

Comment: What's the condition for showing one or the other?

Comment: You haven't tagged jQuery. Are you loading it for this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var btnOne = document.getElementById('one');
var btnTwo = document.getElementById('two');

btnOne.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("table2").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("table2").style.display = "none";
});

btnTwo.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("table1").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("table2").style.display = "none";
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/2u0ytrk1/)**

If you're using jQuery (mentioned by not tagged), things are simpler:

```
$('#btnOne').click(function() {
  $('#table1').show();
  $('#table2').hide;
});

$('#btnTwo').click(function() {
  $('#table2').show();
  $('#table1').hide;
});
```

**[Demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/2u0ytrk1/4/)**

Comment: I'm like to plain javascript for show and hide. However, I have done the same code but working like yours.

Answer (score 1):

I think this answer may help you.

```js
function hideTable(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
}

function showTable(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}

showTable('test1');
hideTable('test2');
```

```html
<table id="test1" class="display" width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><b>Name :</b> <label for="nme" style="vertical-align: middle"></label></td>
        <td><b>Expanded Name :</b> <label for="frml_nme" style="vertical-align: middle"></label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="test2" class="display" width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><b>Feed Name :</b> <label for="feed_id" style="vertical-align: middle"></label></td>
        <td><b>Source :</b> <label for="source" style="vertical-align: middle"></label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="showTable('test1');hideTable('test2')">Show table 1</button>
<button onclick="showTable('test2');hideTable('test1')">Show table 2</button>
```

Comment: Good, but better to keep JavaScript out of the markup.

Answer (score 0):

something like that?

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>


<body>
    <style>
        #test1,
            #test2 {
                display: none;
            }

        </style>

    <table id="test1" class="display" width="100%" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td><b>Name :</b> <label for="nme" style="vertical-align: middle"></label></td>
            <td><b>Expanded Name :</b> <label for="frml_nme" style="vertical-align: middle"></label></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <table id="test2" class="display" width="100%" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td><b>Feed Name :</b> <label for="feed_id" style="vertical-align: middle"></label></td>
            <td><b>Source :</b> <label for="source" style="vertical-align: middle"></label></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="tbl1" onclick="open1()">
    <input type="button" value="tbl2" onclick="open2()">

    <script>
        function open1() {
            document.getElementById("test1").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("test2").style.display = "none";

        }

        function open2() {
            document.getElementById("test2").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("test1").style.display = "none";

        }

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to show on page load. How to hide every thing ?